# Prove if $u,v,w$ linearly independent then ${\{u+v+w,v-w,2w}\}$ linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, independence, solution-verification

> Prove if $u,v,w$ linearly independent then ${\{u+v+w,v-w,2w}\}$
>   linearly independent

what I did is :

I need to Prove that for  $x,y,z  \in F$

$x(u+v+w) + y(v-w) + z(2w) = 0 $

implies that $x=y=z=0$

$x(u+v+w) + y(v-w) + z(2w) = xu  + xv + xw + yv - yw + 2zw =  $

$= (x)u + (x+y)v + (x-y+2z)w =0$

$ u,v,w $    linearly independent $\rightarrow   x=0  $  and $x+y=0$ and $(x-y+2z)=0$ $\rightarrow x=y=z=0$

is that enough to prove the question ?

thanks

Comment: The approach is correct, the phrasing "I need to find ... such that ... and ... " is not. The correct one would be "I need to prove that ...=0 implies that x=y=z=0".

Comment: @A.Γ. I fixed it .. thank alot

Answer (score 1):

The systematic way is to consider matrices:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} u' \\ v' \\ w' \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & \hphantom{-}1 \\ 0 & 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & \hphantom{-}2 \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} u \\ v \\ w \end{pmatrix}
$$
The matrix is triangular with nonzero diagonal entries. Therefore, it is invertible.

Thus, the subspace generated by $u',v',w'$ is the same as the subspace generated by $u,v,w$.

Comment: This formalization seems confusing for students. Where did it come from? I have seen this many times and do not like it. Symbolically it is ok, but a student (without much abstract algebra knowledge) is used to think of a vector as a three-dimensional column (or $n$-dimensional at best). Here we see three such vectors on top of each other (to the left). Is it 9-dimensional vector? I believe it is better to transpose the whole thing.

Comment: @A. Г. That silly conception that you rightly point out the typical student would tend to entertain is one of the first things the said students should get rid of.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick hint to a speedier solution, notice you have the following relation:

$$\begin{pmatrix} u'\\v' \\w' \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} u+v+w \\ v-w \\ 2w \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1_K & 1_K & 1_K \\ 0_K & 1_K & -1_K \\ 0_K & 0_K & 2_K \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} u\\ v\\ w \end{pmatrix}$$

where $K$ is the unspecified field of scalars of the unspecified vector space $V$ you are considering and where for any integer $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ we denote $n_K=n1_K$.

The square matrix of order $3$ that has appeared --let us call it $A$-- is upper triangular and as long as $\mathrm{char}\ K \neq 2$ (in other words as long as $2_K \neq 0_K$) all the diagonal entries will be nonzero hence invertible hence the whole matrix will be invertible.